# How to browse android emulator SD on Windows without Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can't understand how to browse android emulator sd card. I am using IDEA, not Eclipse and can't use Eclipse tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [DDMS](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html). It is available as a standalone tool, in addition to the Eclipse perspective.

Answer (score 9):

Or you can also use `adb` located in `android-sdk-directory/tools`.

To do this open up a command line and type `adb shell` when developing on Linux or `adb.exe shell` when developing on Windows then you will be logged in into your Android emulator where you can simply use basic UNIX commands to navigate to the SDcard. 
 You'd do that like this `cd /sdcard` and to list whats in there you us `ls`.

Hope it helped.

Comment: But just so you know CommonsWare's method works too. You'll get an easier visual way to explore the content of the SDcard.

Comment: As I understand DDMS required Eclipse usage. I am not right? As I mentioned earlier I am usin Intellij IDEA

Comment: Oh no no. What CommonWare meant is that you can use DDMS without Eclipse.

Comment: Please tell about CommonsWare's method. Just visited their site but see only books, training... Ability to visual browse will be much better than shell

Comment: Actually it's just the link he has posted. You just have to invoke ddms.exe (not sure tho I'm using Linux) from a command line and DDMS will get started.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Now I understand all! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html#ImDisk). Very easy to mount the iso file, just right click on it and choose mount from the menu. Add/Remove files as there will appear a new mounted unit and once done, right click and unmount. I also assumed you are running windows, as a nix user wouldn't ask such question :)

Comment: I know many tools for mounting ISO, but I have SD image as IMG file. I can change emulator SD card on ISO format? How?

Comment: Maybe it is an img file instead of iso (can't check atm). ImDisk mounts it anyways. It's a small and very simple app, that's why I like it.

Comment: I already used tool with IMG mounting support (http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) but this tool can't mount android sd image, error occures.

Comment: If you tried it, then magicdisc can't mount it. ImDisk on the other hand mounts it just fine as I have used it for quite some time.