# Where is the SD card of eclipse android emulator in windows?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-sdcard

Where I can see the SD card directory of the eclipse android emulator is located in windows? I have created and deleted 2-3 AVDs each with 512, 1024mb SD cards so I don't want to get that space wasted. If I find it out I can directly delete it from windows. Does that space allocated for the SD card be automatically unallocated after I delete the AVD? I created the AVD card from the AVD edit option window.

Comment: you want to see the SD location of the emulator right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the space is temporary, but you could check for yourself with Filemon (now part of Process Explorer) during the creation process: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 (I'd do it myself, but I no longer have a Windows machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can see the SD-card of emulator.

Go to DDMS -> Click on Filer Explorer -> Mnt ->SD-card where you can see all your file.

If you don't find Sd-card inside DDMS then might be you have not allocated space for SD-card if it is so then add it like this

[image]

After allocating space you will be able to use that space as SD-card.

`Does that space allocated for the SD card be automatically unallocated after I delete the AVD?`

Yes when you delete AVD it will automatically delete all the file which you have created and un-allocate space.

Comment: Is there any other way without going to DDMS ? Because my DDMS's can't pull database file and I don't use default Emulator. I'm using GennyMotion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DDMS perspective to view and manipulate files stored is SD card.

Read [this](http://androidforums.com/application-development/463412-how-access-files-in-avd-sd-card.html) too about Emulator SD cards

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662553/how-to-browse-android-emulator-sd-on-windows-without-eclipse) answers too.

Answer (score 1):

Hiii,

Go to DDMS, After that

internal sdcard path is **DDMS->File Explorer->mnt->sdcard**

and you give sdcard size at the time to create AVD then

External sdcard path is **DDMS->File Explorer->sdcard**

Answer (score 1):

In the DDMS view of eclipse, Open "File Explorer" Tab of your emulator.
Inside that you will find sdcard location as: mnt>sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it under DDMS as so many answer here, i am adding graphical view to it_
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. First create the Sdcard when create the AVD
2. Run the emulator
3. select DDMS, in eclipse.[image]

Internal sdcard path : **DDMS->File Explorer->mnt->sdcard**

External sdcard path : **DDMS->File Explorer->storage->sdcard**

[image]